# How to change class implementation efficiently

Tags: python

I'd like to change the implementation depending on a constructor argument. Below is an example showing what I mean:

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, simulate):
        self.simulate = simulate

    def foo(self):
        if simulate:
            self._simulate_foo()
        else:
            self._do_foo()

    def _do_foo(self):
        # do foo

    def _simulate_foo(self):
        # simulate foo
```

Now every call to `foo()` invokes an `if` clause. To avoid that I could bind the correct method dynamically to `foo`.

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, simulate):
        if simulate:
            self.foo = self._simulate_foo
        else:
            self.foo = self._do_foo()

    def _do_foo(self):
        # do foo

    def _simulate_foo(self):
        # simulate foo
```

Are there any drawbacks why this should not be done or other drawbacks I'm not aware? Is this really faster?(I'm aware that inheritance is another option)

Comment: How often is `foo` getting called? Unless you've profiled and found the overhead of the `if` is a real problem, this looks like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: "Is this really faster?"  Well, you've probably spent more time working on optimizing it than you'd ever save in practice. :^)  Don't guess, though: use `timeit` and find out.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) refactoring instead, as it solves your problem in a more elegant way than both the current code and the suggested alternative:

```
class Device(object):
    def foo(self):
        # do foo

class SimulatedDevice(object):
    def foo(self):
        # simulate foo
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is perfectly fine, and you'll find the technique used in plenty of Python frameworks. However, you may want to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to check if this is really faster.

When you access `instance.foo`, Python will first look for it in the class definition to make sure it's not a data descriptor (such as a property), then look it up in the instance namespace, but this is a very fast lookup since `foo` is not defined in the class (setting `self.foo` stores it in the instance `__dict__` namespace).

The `if` statement is almost certainly *slower* than that double lookup, since the `if` statement itself needs to look up `self.simulate` in the same manner, but the difference will be negligible.